# is it possible to test the contents of a function that is the parameter of a spy

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, spy

I'm testing a directive in angular and for code coverage purposes i need to get into that function which is passed to the second parameter of the remove function:

```
Myservice.remove(param1, function() {
   //test contents of this..
});
```

however `Myservice` is mocked, with the `remove` function being a spy:

```
myservice = {
    remove: jasmine.createSpy('Myservice.remove')
}
```

I've tried `callThrough()` and `callFake()` but i believe these are more to just return the result of remove, not cover the parameter function, so naturally i get no difference.

so in my test i have the following:

```
it('should do something', function() {
    // generic directive setup
    expect(myservice.remove).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

this works and the tests passes, however i'm unable to cover that function in the param, any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to call a fake function with the correct params in and then calling the function within it.

```
myservice = {
    remove: jasmine.createSpy('Myservice.remove').and.callFake(function(data, callback) {
        callback();
    });
}
```

the same test passes, but now the coverage fully covers the function passed in as the param.